# How to send CTRL + V to a remote SSH shell in CMD on Windows 11?

Tags: ssh, cmd.exe, windows-11

Started CMD, then used an SSH shell to remote into a Linux server. When I'm trying to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to a Vim plugin, CMD tries to paste whatever is on my clipboard. Is there an escape sequence? Should I use PowerShell instead?

I tried WSL 2 (with the default distro of Ubuntu) shell, but SSH just hangs.  This is a [known open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7971) when trying to `ssh` into VMs on the same Windows 11 machine on the same subnet, but `ssh.exe` works from WSL 2 terminals - but that opens the remote session in CMD so back to square one.

There's an open issue, [Method to suppress the default CTRL+C/CTRL+V mapping specifically for WSL; profile-specific keybindings? #5790](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5790), so this may not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the top bar of the terminal window
2. Open the menu by clicking at <kbd>V</kbd>
3. Select settings `Settings`
4. On the sidebar, select `Actions`
5. Find the `Paste` action that has <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> has assigned.
6. Click on the edit button.
7. Either assign a new combination or delete it (there are other `Paste` entries as well).

   To edit:

   7a. Click in the area where <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> is visible.

   7b. Press the new key combination to replace it.

   7c. Click checkmark.
8. Hit `Save` at the bottom of the page.

[image]

<sup>Used [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) to record. If I were on Linux, then I would have used [peek](https://github.com/phw/peek).</sup>